# updating multiple x-editable fields at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, x-editable

I'm a little stuck with this issue...

I have a modal with two x-editable fields for latitude and longitude, and below (in the modal body) there is a map

if I update the latitude or longitude and save the map updates. This works fine, except it's a very cumbersome process to have to look up the coordinates and then enter them, it's much easier to just drag the marker and update the values after. I've got the marker to be draggable and I can get the values and update the fields.

I'm undecided whether the values should be updated automatically after each drag, or wait 'till user presses save. I'm leaning toward the press save, see both fields update, then close modal. In either case, I need to be able to save the input from a separate call.

How do I update multiple values, and display verification after a custom call?